# How can I change this code for email form validation to run correctly?

Tags: javascript

Here is my js. I am trying to create an email form validation and it isn't working. Every time submit is clicked it automatically sends you to google(which is where it is supposed to send you if the input is valid) even if it just blank or incorrect.

```
var txtEmail = document.querySelector("email");
var txtFeedback = document.querySelector('#txtFeedback');
var errorDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("error");





formReference.addEventListener('submit', onFormSubmit);


function onFormSubmit(event) {


    var isValid = true;


    //clear out the feedback div
   txtFeedback.innerHTML = "";

   //clear out the error divs
   for(var i = 0; i < errorDivs.length; i++) {
    errorDivs[i].innerHTML = "";
  }


  if ( txtEmail.value == "" || !/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(txtEmail.value)){
isValid = false;
txtFeedback.innerHTML += "<p>Please enter a valid email address.</p>";
txtEmail.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email    address."


  } if(!isValid) {
    event.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #txtFeedback {
           color: #FF0000;

      }
       .error {
           display: inline;
           color: #FF0000;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="txtFeedback"></div>
<form action="http://www.google.com" id="myForm">
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input id="email"/>
        <div class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
    </div>
    </form>
<script src = "js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should your querySelector reference for `txtEmail` be `#email` instead of just `email`?

Comment: can you add your HTML ?

Comment: no that doesnt change anything

Comment: Are you sure you are entering in the last if ? Did you try to put an alert in it, or set up a breakpoint ? From what I remember, you should also add a ` return false ; ` in the last if to prevent the form from sending the data.

Comment: I am just putting in random letters for the email and it is running as if it is valid. If my regular expression is correct, then I believe if an input is invalid the `txtFeedback` should run saying please enter a valid email address

Comment: `if(!isValid) {
    event.preventDefault();
   }` acts as the same thing as adding return false

Answer (score 0):

your first line selects `email` elements.

change it to select element with id of email:

```
var txtEmail = document.querySelector("#email");
```

and you didn't declared `formReference` in your code.

I declared it like this and it works just fine.

```
var formReference = document.getElementById('myForm');
```